# Why does shell ignore asterisk glob

Tags: shell

I have the following Code:

```
#!/bin/sh (it is dash for me)
#... lines of code
dir="/home/user/files/" #as example, actually passed as commandline argument
for file in "$dir"/*.java; do
   echo "$file"
done
```

The output I get is:
`/home/user/files//*.java`

Why is my shell ignoring the glob in this case?

Edit: I checked the directory for existing Java files of course. There are Java Files in that directory.

The thing is when I give it the absolut directory name instead of the variable it seems to work

Edit 2: Ok, nevermind! It was as simply as a misspelling in the commandline argument! Sorry I had to bother you with that, I've been looking for the problem for some time and simply got stuck. But thank you for taking your time in trying to find a solution!

Comment: This is normal and expected if no file names ending in `.java` exist in the given directory.

Comment: If you believe that the directory _should_ contain files matching the expression, I'd consider using bash instead of dash for temporary testing purposes, as in bash `set -x` will escape nonprinting characters in such a way to make their presence in your variables visible.

Comment: (there's also a flag that can disable globbing, but since it's off by default, if the problem really reproduces when given only the code included in the question that isn't the situation here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [section 2.13.3](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03) of the POSIX shell specification:

> If the pattern does not match any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern string shall be left unchanged.

It's not ignoring the glob, it simply failed to match any files. You didn't have any Java source files in the directory.

---

Other shells can modify this behavior. To give two examples,

- `bash` treated a non-matching pattern literally by default, but has options to treat one as either an error or a null list (in which case the loop wouldn't even be entered).
- `zsh` has similar options, but defaults to treating the pattern as an error.